# Can we setup threshold based email notification in Javamelody

Tags: java, jira

I am using [Javamelody](http://code.google.com/p/javamelody/) plugin for Jira, and would like to know if i can setup CPU/Disk etc thresholds, and be notified via email when those are crossed , with PDF of system profile as attachment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could setup a monitor to watch the contents of the RRD files Javamelody writes to. You can find them here (where /opt/jira is your $JIRA_INST directory and `_host-atlassian01` is your hostname):

```
$ ls /opt/jira/temp/javamelody/_host-atlassian01/*.rrd | grep -v [2-9]
/opt/jira/temp/javamelody/_host-atlassian01/activeConnections.rrd
/opt/jira/temp/javamelody/_host-atlassian01/activeThreads.rrd
/opt/jira/temp/javamelody/_host-atlassian01/cpu.rrd
/opt/jira/temp/javamelody/_host-atlassian01/fileDescriptors.rrd
/opt/jira/temp/javamelody/_host-atlassian01/gc.rrd
/opt/jira/temp/javamelody/_host-atlassian01/httpHitsRate.rrd
/opt/jira/temp/javamelody/_host-atlassian01/httpMeanTimes.rrd
/opt/jira/temp/javamelody/_host-atlassian01/httpSessionsMeanAge.rrd
/opt/jira/temp/javamelody/_host-atlassian01/httpSessions.rrd
/opt/jira/temp/javamelody/_host-atlassian01/httpSystemErrors.rrd
/opt/jira/temp/javamelody/_host-atlassian01/jspHitsRate.rrd
/opt/jira/temp/javamelody/_host-atlassian01/jspMeanTimes.rrd
/opt/jira/temp/javamelody/_host-atlassian01/jspSystemErrors.rrd
/opt/jira/temp/javamelody/_host-atlassian01/loadedClassesCount.rrd
/opt/jira/temp/javamelody/_host-atlassian01/sqlHitsRate.rrd
/opt/jira/temp/javamelody/_host-atlassian01/sqlMeanTimes.rrd
/opt/jira/temp/javamelody/_host-atlassian01/sqlSystemErrors.rrd
/opt/jira/temp/javamelody/_host-atlassian01/systemLoad.rrd
/opt/jira/temp/javamelody/_host-atlassian01/threadCount.rrd
/opt/jira/temp/javamelody/_host-atlassian01/tomcatBusyThreads.rrd
/opt/jira/temp/javamelody/_host-atlassian01/tomcatBytesReceived.rrd
/opt/jira/temp/javamelody/_host-atlassian01/tomcatBytesSent.rrd
/opt/jira/temp/javamelody/_host-atlassian01/usedConnections.rrd
/opt/jira/temp/javamelody/_host-atlassian01/usedMemory.rrd
/opt/jira/temp/javamelody/_host-atlassian01/usedNonHeapMemory.rrd
/opt/jira/temp/javamelody/_host-atlassian01/usedPhysicalMemorySize.rrd
/opt/jira/temp/javamelody/_host-atlassian01/usedSwapSpaceSize.rrd
```